# Foundations in category theory

Tags: category-theory

I'm new in this study and I don't know much about the foundations of mathematics, so I have a question. 
If I'm doing category theory, and I need to talk about "small categories" , "locally small" and etc, I need to have some set theory foundation like NBG where I can talk about this things, right? But, if I want to take the category of all categories, I will have some problem in this context with NBG as foundation?

Comment: Well, yes, a category of all categories is a problem the same way that a set of all sets is a problem (particularly since all sets can be considered discrete categories). You get by without it (with a proper class of small categories, or Grothendieck universes), or you implement it in a theory that can't handle it very well ($\mathsf{NF(U)}$ or $\mathsf{GPK}$).

Comment: You don't really want to take the category of all categories anyway – it won't be as well behaved as the category of small categories. (For instance, it fails to be cartesian closed.)

Comment: @ZhenLin I have made some conversation in HoTT IRC group, and have an impression that in HoTT, this kind of problem do not exist anymore because we have a hierarchy of universes... Is this true?

Comment: Sure, and in set theory you can equally well add the universe axiom.

Answer (score 3):

This may be a little deeper than you're looking for, but the papers numbered 58 and 62 on [this list](http://math.stanford.edu/~feferman/papers.html) are ones that I found thought-provoking. Foundations of category theory is a subject that Feferman has returned to a few times, and he has the nice device of a recurring list of requirements for his ideal theory. He largely hovers near NFU-esque theories, but I think they should be of interest even if you're interested in more conventional foundations in the long run.

---

As for NBG, remember that we define categories as tuples, and generally as Kuratowski tuples. So with any collection of small categories, we can apply sumset a few times and an instance of separation to get, say, the collection of all the objects of those categories. So if we had a collection of all small categories, we could apply sumset/separation a few times to get the collection of all sets. In NBG or a similar theory, one needs to simply let some categories not be members of anything. In practice, this isn't such a big deal, and a few extensions of the theory exist that give us a bit more elbow room among the sets if needed.

Comment: Thanks for that link.  There's so many things there I want to read that I'm not sure where to start.

Comment: @MJD: Same here. I've only read the barest smattering of Feferman's corpus so far :p